# Как получить список объектов от контролёра Spring на странице jsp в функцию ajax(jquery)

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring

На странице `jsp` через ajax/jquery отправляю данные на контролер/Spring, там сохраняю в базу-достаю и отправляю назад в виде списка.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function funkSuccess(data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            $("#p1").text("текст_метка");
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#send_message").bind("click", function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<c:url value="/add_message"/>",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: ({text: $("#text_message").val()}),
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: funkSuccess
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

...

```
<input id="text_message" type="text" placeholder="текст сообщения" autofocus>
<button id="send_message" type="submit">отправить</button>
<br>
<p id="p1"></p>
```

...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "add_message", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addMessage(@RequestParam(value = "text") String str,
                           HttpServletResponse response) {
        Message message = new Message(str);
        serviceMessage.add(message);
        List<Message> list = serviceMessage.findAll(lastDate);
        try {
            response.getWriter().print(list);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

...

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long idUser;

    private long sender;

    private String text;

    private long recipient;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date date = new Date();
...
```

Проблема в том что ajax не может распарсить приходящие данные `data = JSON.parse(data);`. Не работает только с самописными классами, если в дженерике отправляемого списка использовать встроенный класс, например `Integer`, то всё нормально, это видно по отработке функции `<script>..funcSuccess..."текст_метка"..</script>`. Как исправить проблему? И подскажите, как потом пройтись по приходящему на страницу списку объектов обращаясь к их полям( в функции `funcSuccess` блока `<script></script>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить `@ResponseBody` и просто возвращать список.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "add_message", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public List<Message> addMessage(@RequestParam(value = "text") String str) {
    Message message = new Message(str);
    serviceMessage.add(message);
    List<Message> list = serviceMessage.findAll(lastDate);
    return list;
}
```

В ajax уже полученный список можно использовать.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#send_message").bind("click", function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<c:url value="/add_message"/>",
                type: "POST",
                data: ({text: $("#text_message").val()}),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(list) {
                    console.log(list);
                    // или через цикл
                    $.each(list, function(key, value) {
                       console.log(value.text);
                    });
             }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно сериализовать возвражаемый список в json.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "add_message", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public List<Message> addMessage(@RequestParam(value = "text") String str) {
    Message message = new Message(str);
    serviceMessage.add(message);
    return serviceMessage.findAll(lastDate);
}
```

Comment: `@NickSavenia` Так тоже не работает, в таком случае не работает даже со встроенными классами. Я забыл упомянуть в вопросе, что я использую Spring mvc  @Controller, а не @RestController, если это имеет значение.